# Is "they had already ten children" wrong?

Tags: grammar, word-order, syntax

The following example is from the Longman Dictionary of Common Errors. It marks the first as wrong and the latter two as correct.

> ✗ They had already ten children and didn't want any more.
>
> ✔ They already had ten children and didn't want any more.
>
> ✔ They had ten children already and didn't want any more.

Does this classification correspond with your experience? To my ears, "had already ten" sounds fine.

edit: My native language is German, where "Sie hatten bereits zehn Kinder" is the default sentence structure.

Comment: As far as common usage goes, this classification is correct. However, I could definitely see the "wrong" version being used in an artistic format like poetry.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yes, I meant it cannot come after a verb in the simple tense like that. "They had already had ten children by the time x occurred".[that would be with an auxiliary] I just wasn't paying attention....

Comment: They already had ten children (yes). They had ten children already (yes). They had already had ten children,. (yes).

Comment: I would not say “had already ten” is definitely wrong; I believe I've heard educated natives say analogous sentences when speaking ex tempore.  But in writing it suggests word-for-word translation from a foreign language.

Answer (score 3):

*"They had already ten children" is ungrammatical because an adverb, in general, cannot intervene between a verb and a direct object.

The sentence below, however, is OK:

"They have already had ten children"

That's because the first "have" is an auxiliary, not a lexical verb. An auxiliary does not take a direct object.

Comment: It depends on the adverb. They have only two children.

Comment: @Lambie I'd say it depends on the modifying scope. In that sentence, "only" is a peripheral modifier. It modifies, and therefore is part of, the noun phrase "only two children".

Comment: If you say *already* and *ten* together quickly, the sentence suddenly becomes less ungrammatical! Maybe? : (